# How to turn off k fold cross validation in rpart() in r

Tags: r, tree, cross-validation, rpart

I have the Bitcoin time series, I use 11 technical indicators as features and I want to fit a regression tree to the data. As far as I know, there are 2 functions in r which can create regression trees, i.e. rpart() and tree(), but both functions do not seem appropriate. rpart() uses k-fold cross validation to validate the optimal cost complexity parameter cp and in tree(), it is not possible to specify the value of cp.

I am aware that cv.tree() looks for the optimal value of cp via cross validation, but again, cv.tee() uses k-fold cross validation. Since I have a time series, and therefore temporal dependencies, I do not want to use k-fold cross validation, because k-fold cross validation will randomly divide the data into k-fold, fit the model on k-1 folds and calculate the MSE on the left out k-th fold, and then the sequence of my time series is obviously ruined.

I found an argument of the rpart() function, i.e. xval, which is supposed to let me specify the number of cross validations, but when I look at the output of the rpart() function call when xval=0, it doesn't seem like cross validation is turned off. Below you can see my function call and the output:

```
tree.model= rpart(Close_5~ M+ DSMA+ DWMA+ DEMA+ CCI+ RSI+ DKD+ R+ FI+ DVI+ 
OBV, data= train.subset, method= "anova", control= 
rpart.control(cp=0.01,xval= 0, minbucket = 5))

> summary(tree.model)
Call:
rpart(formula = Close_5 ~ M + DSMA + DWMA + DEMA + CCI + RSI + 
DKD + R + FI + DVI + OBV, data = train.subset, method = "anova", 
control = rpart.control(cp = 0.01, xval = 0, minbucket = 5))
n= 590 

           CP nsplit rel error
1  0.35433076      0 1.0000000
2  0.10981049      1 0.6456692
3  0.06070669      2 0.5358587
4  0.04154720      3 0.4751521
5  0.02415633      5 0.3920576
6  0.02265346      6 0.3679013
7  0.02139752      8 0.3225944
8  0.02096500      9 0.3011969
9  0.02086543     10 0.2802319
10 0.01675277     11 0.2593665
11 0.01551861     13 0.2258609
12 0.01388126     14 0.2103423
13 0.01161287     15 0.1964610
14 0.01127722     16 0.1848482
15 0.01000000     18 0.1622937
```

It seems like rpart() cross validated 15 different values of cp. If these values were tested with k-fold cross validation, then again, the sequence of my time series will be ruined and I can basically not use these results. Does anyone know how I can turn off cross validation in rpart() effectively, or how to vary the value of cp in tree()?

UPDATE: I followed the suggestion of one of our colleagues and set xval=1, but that didn't seem to solve the problem. You can see the full function output when xval=1 [here](http://kevinsuedmersen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/rpart-output-1.txt). Btw, parameters[j] is the j-th element of a parameter vector. When I called this function, parameters[j]= 0.0009765625

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought about using the [`caret`](https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) package? It supports [rolling forecasting origin techniques](https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#time) (among many other useful things).

Comment: How are you setting up your data? Are you creating lag variables and including them as features in the model? Are you including date attributes as features? Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The `cp` parameter in `rpart()` is the complexity parameter, and constrains the overall lack of fit that must be improved at each step. It affects the behavior of cross validation, but  it varies regardless of the value of the`xval` control parameter.

Comment: @LenGreski thanks for your comment. I have calculated 11 technical indicators from the open, high, low and close prices of Bitcoin which I use as independent variables. I don't have any lagged values of the Bitcoin price itself as independent variable. I spent at least 100 lines of code to calculate these technical indicators, so how would you suggest to provide the minimal, complete and verifiable example? I could definitely upload the data frame and my entire code to my website and link it to my question, if that helps. Then, you could reproduce the problem, but it will be a lot of info.

Comment: @markus, Thanks for your comment. I looked at the caret package and it seems like it can do a lot of stuff. I spent 15 minutes going through it, but I didn't find anything about regression trees. Could you provide my with some pseudo code, how you would use the caret package to fit regression trees while keeping cross-validation turned off and while specifying come cost-complexity parameters?

Comment: @KevinSüdmersen Perhaps `library(caret); fit <- train(x = x, y = y, method = "rpart", trControl = trainControl(method = "none"), metric = "RMSE", tuneGrid = data.frame(cp=0.01), preProcess = c("center", "scale"), xval = 0, minbucket = 5)`. For [`method = rpart`](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#tree-based-model) `caret` let's you only tune over (or fix) `cp` in the `tuneGrid` argument,  but not `xval` or `minbucket` that's why we need to supply them via the `...` argument. `x` are your features, `y` vector of outcome variable. Hope this helps.

Comment: @KevinSüdmersen -  the minimal example would be  to post a subset of the data with `dput()` after you've created your independent variables. Another approach would be to illustrate your problem with sample data that's already available in R.  I went ahead and posted an answer, illustrating it with the `Ozone` data set from the `mlbench` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To demonstrate that `rpart()` is creating tree nodes by iterating over declining values of `cp` versus resampling, we'll use the `Ozone` data from the `mlbench` package to compare the results of `rpart()` and `caret::train()` as discussed in the comments to the OP. We'll setup the Ozone data as illustrated in the CRAN documentation for [Support Vector Machines](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf), which support nonlinear regression and are comparable to `rpart()`.

```
library(rpart)
library(caret)
data(Ozone, package = "mlbench")
# split into test and training
index <- 1:nrow(Ozone)
set.seed(01381708)
testIndex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index) / 3))
testset <- na.omit(Ozone[testIndex,-3])
trainset <- na.omit(Ozone[-testIndex,-3])


# rpart version
set.seed(95014) #reset seed to ensure sample is same as caret version
rpart.model <- rpart(V4 ~ .,data = trainset,xval=0)
# summary(rpart.model)
# calculate RMSE
rpart.pred <- predict(rpart.model, testset[,-3])
crossprod(rpart.pred - testset[,3]) / length(testIndex)
```

...and the output for the RMSE calculation:

```
> crossprod(rpart.pred - testset[,3]) / length(testIndex)
         [,1]
[1,] 18.25507
```

Next, we'll run the same analysis with `caret::train()` as proposed in the comments to the OP.

```
# caret version
set.seed(95014)
rpart.model <- caret::train(x = trainset[,-3],
                            y = trainset[,3],method = "rpart", trControl = trainControl(method = "none"), 
                            metric = "RMSE", tuneGrid = data.frame(cp=0.01), 
                            preProcess = c("center", "scale"), xval = 0, minbucket = 5)
# summary(rpart.model)
# demonstrate caret version did not do resampling
rpart.model
# calculate RMSE, which matches RMSE from rpart() 
rpart.pred <- predict(rpart.model, testset[,-3])
crossprod(rpart.pred - testset[,3]) / length(testIndex)
```

When we print the model output from `caret::train()` it clearly notes that there was no resampling.

```
> rpart.model
CART 

135 samples
 11 predictor

Pre-processing: centered (9), scaled (9), ignore (2) 
Resampling: None
```

The RMSE for the `caret::train()` version matches the RMSE from `rpart()`.

```
> # calculate RMSE, which matches RMSE from rpart() 
> rpart.pred <- predict(rpart.model, testset[,-3])
> crossprod(rpart.pred - testset[,3]) / length(testIndex)
         [,1]
[1,] 18.25507
>
```

## Conclusions

First, as configured above, neither `caret::train()` nor `rpart()` are resampling. If one prints the model output, however, one will see multiple values of `cp` are used to generate the final tree of 47 nodes via both techniques.

### Output from caret `summary(rpart.model)`

```
          CP nsplit rel error
1 0.58951537      0 1.0000000
2 0.08544094      1 0.4104846
3 0.05237152      2 0.3250437
4 0.04686890      3 0.2726722
5 0.03603843      4 0.2258033
6 0.02651451      5 0.1897648
7 0.02194866      6 0.1632503
8 0.01000000      7 0.1413017
```

### Output from rpart `summary(rpart.model)`

```
          CP nsplit rel error
1 0.58951537      0 1.0000000
2 0.08544094      1 0.4104846
3 0.05237152      2 0.3250437
4 0.04686890      3 0.2726722
5 0.03603843      4 0.2258033
6 0.02651451      5 0.1897648
7 0.02194866      6 0.1632503
8 0.01000000      7 0.1413017
```

Second, both models account for time values via the inclusion of `month` and `day` variables as independent variables. In the `Ozone` data set, `V1` is the month variable, and `V2` is the day variable. All data was collected during 1976, so there is no year variable included in the data set, and in the original analysis in the `svm` vignette, day of week was dropped prior to analysis.

Third, to account for other time-based effects using algorithms like `rpart()` or `svm()` when date attributes are not used as features in the model, one must include lag effects as features in the model because these algorithms do not directly account for a time component. One example of how to do this with an ensemble of regression trees using a range of lagged values is [Ensemble Regression Trees for Time Series Predictions](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/998d/61d8df62eaf85a697668c0c8c7570f6848c0.pdf).

Comment: It is really amazing to see how much effort people put into solving other people's problems, I highly appreciate it! The output of both methods is interesting and confusing at the same time. As far as I understand now, both function calls do not do re-sampling, but they use different values of cp to generate one and the same tree. So my first question is: How could you tell both functions to use only the cp value which I specified?

Comment: @KevinSüdmersen - my answer does use only one value of cp, 0.01. Think of it this way, setting cp=.01 in the function argument means “keep splitting trees until the percentage of variance explained is less than 0.01.”

Comment: My second question is related to the third point of your conslusion: As far as I understand, I have to modify the data frame, before I can use Ensemble Regression Trees for TS Prediction. I tried to understand the procedure which was outlined in the paper you linked to and searched in Google, but unfortunately, it is not clear to me yet. Do you know any good resources which explain how to "include lag effects as features in the model", or would it be possible for you to show me how to set up my data frame assuming I have predictors X_1, X_2, X_3 and Y as dependent variable?

Comment: Replying to: "@KevinSüdmersen - my answer does use only one value of cp, 0.01. Think of it this way, setting cp=.01 in the function argument means “keep splitting trees until the percentage of variance explained is less than 0.01.”" --> Ahh, so I have to interpret the output of `summary(rpart.model)` like this: At the first split, the percentage of variance explained (POVE) is `0.58951537`, at the second split, the POVE is `0.08544094`, and rpart keeps splitting, until the POVE falls below our pre-specified value of `0.01`

Comment: This will effectively answer my original question (I assume it's called OP) now, so I will mark your answer as "answered", but if you have any other support material to my second question, I would be pleased to hear about it

Comment: @KevinSüdmersen - yes, when cp=.01 the algorithm will keep splitting trees until then next split improves the POVE by less than .01. Note that the POVE interpretation is specific to `method="anova"` tree splitting, per the `rpart.control` documentation. Regarding your second question, it merits a new question on SO. Please post it as a second question, and I'll provide an answer.

Comment: @KevinSüdmersen You might find this blog post on [Using regression trees for forecasting double-seasonal time series with trend in R](https://petolau.github.io/Regression-trees-for-forecasting-time-series-in-R/) useful. Regards

Comment: @LenGreski, Before I write a new question about how to construct the data matrix for time-series forecasts related to point 3 of your conclusion, I would like to ask you about the second point of your conclusion: Does that mean that I have to include time variables/indices in the function call, i.e.`tree.model= rpart(Close_5~Date+ Hour+ Minute+ M+ DSMA+ DWMA+ DEMA+ CCI+ RSI+ DKD+ R+ FI+ DVI+ OBV, data= train.subset, method= "anova", control= rpart.control(cp= parameters[j], xval= 0, minbucket = 5))` ?

Comment: @KevinSüdmersen - One way to account for time in the model is to use date time elements as features, as was done with the `Ozone` analysis in my answer. Another approach is to use lagged variables as features, as illustrated in [Ensemble Regression Trees for Time Series Analysis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/998d/61d8df62eaf85a697668c0c8c7570f6848c0.pdf) or Fourier transforms as illustrated in the [blog post](https://petolau.github.io/Regression-trees-for-forecasting-time-series-in-R/) added in the comments above by @markus .

Comment: @LenGreski and markus thanks for your replies and apologies for my confusion. In class, we never dealt with time series data, so this is all new to me. So, since I am using features like a simple, weighted and exponential moving average of the Bitcoin price, I guess I am already including "lagged variables as features", because moving averages "lag" price action. Hence, it makes no sense to include "Date+ Hour+ Minute" in the function call above. Btw, [here](http://kevinsuedmersen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.txt) is my full data with some explanations to the features

Comment: Concerning my question about the data frame construction for ensemble learning methods, I went through the suggested articles, but unfortunately, I still didn't see the light, so I posted it as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591354/how-to-construct-dataframe-for-time-series-data-using-ensemble-learning-methods)

Answer (score 1):

In your model, simply `xval=0` turn off cross validation.

In your output, you have only `CP NSPLIT REL ERROR`, with cross valisation you should have `CP NSPLIT REL ERROR XERROR XSTD`.

`cp` is just your " complexity parameter" (cp=0.01 by default) from 1 to 0.01.

`rel error` is your predicted error on your dataset train / expected loss from root node.

`nsplit` number of node relativ at size of your tree according to `cp`.

Look : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf